# I get the undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

Can anyone expain why i get undefined?

```
function besked(input) {
    let inputstring = String(input)
    result = "";
    for(i = 0; i < inputstring.length; i+=2 )
    {
    result += inputstring[i];
    }
}
console.log(besked("HHeljw OirnFgaeCrs"))
```

Comment: `besked` function returns nothing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default return value in JS functions is undefined so in order to get something else from that function you should do it like so:

```js
function besked(input) {
    let inputstring = String(input)
    result = "";
    
    for(i = 0; i < inputstring.length; i+=2) {
      result += inputstring[i];
    }
    
    return result;
}
console.log(besked("HHeljw OirnFgaeCrs"))
```